# Question about offspring and making a function regarding the population of offspring

Tags: probability

A homologous gene has two alleles $e$ and $E$, with $e$ being recessive and harmful. The proportion of individuals of genotype $Ee$ in the healthy population is $\lambda$. If two parents are both healthy & they have one healthy child. If they then have a second child, what is the probability it will also be healthy as a function of $\lambda$?

So I know that if both parents are healthy their genotypes will either be $Ee$ or $EE$ but I don't really know how to continue on from this fact.

Comment: The healthy first child is evidence that the parents are not both $Ee$.  You need to use Bayes' Theorem to  re-estimate the probability that that they are both $Ee$ in light of this new evidence,

Comment: How is this evidence that they are not both $Ee$? Since even if they were both heterozygous they still have a $\frac{3}{4}$  probability of producing a healthy child.

Comment: Sure, but $\frac 34$ is less than $1$ and the other cases all have healthy kids with  probability $1$.  Think of it this way:  suppose the parents had a billion kids and that all of them were healthy.  You'd agree, in that case, that the parents could not be $(Ee, Ee)$ right?  Remember, evidence is not the same as proof.

Comment: Yeah I'd agree in that case. So if I was now going to use Bayes' Theorem what would I have to set the two events up as? Would it be the following? $\mathbb{P}=(\text{2nd Healthy Child} | \text{At least one parent has genotype} EE)$ or have I completely missed the mark? Thank you

Comment: That's hard to read.   Take your a priori probabilities and compute the probability that the first child is healthy.  That's your denominator.  Your numerator is the probability that the first child is healthy AND the parents are both $Ee$.

Comment: I am posting something below.  I suggest working the computation yourself before looking at what I post.  If nothing else, I did it quickly and I might have made an algebraic error.

Comment: Hi I decided to clean it up a bit and say that event B = Both parents are Ee, H = First child healthy and S = Second child healthy. I then calculated probability of $H \cup B$  as $\frac{3}{4}$ and probability of $H$ being $\frac{13}{16}$. I think these are correct although I'm not so sure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do we know before the first child is born?  At that point, we have no information at all regarding the genetic type of the parents so we must assume that they follow the average population statistics.  That is to say, they are both $Ee$ with probability $\lambda^2$, one is $Ee$ and the other is $EE$ with probability $2\lambda(1-\lambda)$ and they are both $EE$ with probability $(1-\lambda)^2$.

If they are both $Ee$ then the probability that the first child is healthy is $\frac 34$.  In all other cases, the probability is $1$.

Thus our a priori probability that the first child is healthy is $$\Psi=\frac 34\lambda^2+2\lambda(1-\lambda)+(1-\lambda)^2$$

The portion of that which is explained by both parents having type $Ee$ is, of course, $\frac 34\lambda^2$.

Thus, after seeing the first healthy child, we re-estimate the probability that the parents are both $Ee$ as $$P'=\frac 34\lambda^2\Big /\Psi$$

After some calculating we see that this is $$P'=\frac 3{\lambda+2}-\frac 3{\lambda-2}-3$$

Exercise:  confirm that $P'$ is in fact a possible probability, i.e. that it is between $0$ and $1$.  Show also that it is $≤\lambda^2$ with equality only at $\lambda=0,1$. (that makes sense since, for sensible $\lambda$, the first healthy child is evidence, albeit fairly weak, that the parents are not both $Ee$.)

Of course, now that we have the revised estimate for the probability that they are both $Ee$ we see that the probability that the second child is unhealthy is $\frac 14P'$, so the probability that the second child is healthy is $$\boxed {1-\frac 14P'}$$